# Change Value in "broken" .xml File in R

Tags: r, xml

I got a "broken" .xml file with missing header and root element

**myBrokenXML.xml**

```
  <attribute1>false</attribute1>
  <subjects>
    <subject>
      <population>Adult</population>
      <name>adult1</name>
    </subject>
  </subjects>
```

This .xml file is the input for a program that i have to use and the structure cannot be changed.
I would like to change the attribute "name" to adult5.

- I tried using the xml2 package but it requires a proper xml file for `read_xml()` which returns this error message "Extra content at the end of the document"
- I tried reading the file line by line using `readLines` and then writing a new line with `writeLines()` but this again resulted in an error message "cannot write to this connection"

Anny suggestions are greatly appreciated. I am new to R and XML and been at this for hours (and cursed the developers a few times in the process)

Thanks in advance!

Code using xml2:

```
XMLFile <- read_xml("myBrokenXML.xml")
```

Code using readLines/writeLines; would still require to delete the original line

```
  conn <- file("myBrokenXML.xml", open = "r")
  lines <- readLines(conn)
  for (i in 1:length(lines)){
    print(lines[i])
    if (lines[i] == "\t\t<name>adult1</name>"){
      writeLines("\t\t<name>adult5</name>", conn)
    }
  }
```

**GOAL**
i need to change the value of "name" from adult1 to adult5 and the file must be in the same structure (no header, no root element) at the end.

Comment: I don't understand your goal. You need to fix that xml so to read it as a proper xml file? If you wanna read and write on the xml with the second way you need to open it with `file("myBrokenXML.xml", open = "r+")`

Comment: i edited the post to clarify my goal. i will try your suggestion about `file("myBrokenXML.xml", open = "r+")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `read_html` instead of `read_xml`, since `read_html` will attempt to parse even broken documents, whereas `read_xml` requires strict formatting. It is possible to use this fact to create a repaired xml document by creating a new `xml_document` and writing the nodes obtained from `read_html` into it. This function will allow fragments of xml to be repaired into a proper xml document:

```r
fix_xml <- function(xml_path, root_name = "root")
{
  my_xml   <- xml2::xml_new_root("root")
  root     <- xml2::xml_find_all(my_xml, "//root")
  my_html  <- xml2::read_html(xml_path)
  fragment <- xml2::xml_find_first(my_html, xpath = "//body")
  new_root <- xml2::xml_set_name(fragment, root_name)
  new_root <- xml2::xml_replace(root, fragment)
  return(my_xml)
}
```

So we can do:

```
fix_xml("myBrokenXML.xml")
#> {xml_document}
#> <root>
#> [1] <attribute1>false</attribute1>
#> [2] <subjects>\n  <subject>\n <population>Adult</population>\n <name>adult1...
```

Comment: using your method i can repair the xml file, change the values using the xml2 library and the un-fix the file again using readLines to return to the "broken" structure necessary for the program. Thank You!! (i am just realising, you are the same guy that helped me out yesterday :D )

Answer (score 0):

The Answer from Allan Cameron (#1) works fine, as long as your file does not include case sensitive elements.

If someone ever runs into the same problem, here is what worked for me.

```
fix_xml <- function(xmlPath){
  con <- file(xmlPath)
  lines <- readLines(con)

  firstLine <- c("<root>")
  lastLine <- c("</root>")

  lines <- append(lines, firstLine, after = 0)
  lines <- append(lines, lastLine, after = length(lines))

  write(lines, xmlPath)

  close(con)
}
```

This function insert a root element into a "broken" xml file.
The fixed xml file can then be read using `read_xml()` and edited as desired.

The only difference to Allan's answer is, that using `read_html` does not care about upper case letters and reads the whole file as all-lower-case.

My solution is not as versatile, but it keeps upper case letters.